# Performance of Floyd-Warshall in Haskell – Fixing a space leak

Tags: performance, haskell, floyd-warshall, space-leak

I wanted to write an efficient implementation of the Floyd-Warshall all pairs shortest path algorithm in Haskell using `Vector`s to hopefully get good performance.

The implementation is quite straight-forward, but instead of using a 3-dimensional |V|×|V|×|V| matrix, a 2-dimensional vector is used, since we only ever read the previous `k` value.

Thus, the algorithm is really just a series of steps where a 2D vector is passed in, and a new 2D vector is generated. The final 2D vector contains the shortest paths between all nodes (i,j).

My intuition told me that it would be important to make sure that the previous 2D vector was evaluated before each step, so I used `BangPatterns` on the `prev` argument to the `fw` function and the strict `foldl'`:

```
{-# Language BangPatterns #-}

import           Control.DeepSeq
import           Control.Monad       (forM_)
import           Data.List           (foldl')
import qualified Data.Map.Strict     as M
import           Data.Vector         (Vector, (!), (//))
import qualified Data.Vector         as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as V hiding (length, replicate, take)

type Graph = Vector (M.Map Int Double)
type TwoDVector = Vector (Vector Double)

infinity :: Double
infinity = 1/0

-- calculate shortest path between all pairs in the given graph, if there are
-- negative cycles, return Nothing
allPairsShortestPaths :: Graph -> Int -> Maybe TwoDVector
allPairsShortestPaths g v =
  let initial = fw g v V.empty 0
      results = foldl' (fw g v) initial [1..v]
  in if negCycle results
        then Nothing
        else Just results
  where -- check for negative elements along the diagonal
        negCycle a = any not $ map (\i -> a ! i ! i >= 0) [0..(V.length a-1)]

-- one step of the Floyd-Warshall algorithm
fw :: Graph -> Int -> TwoDVector -> Int -> TwoDVector
fw g v !prev k = V.create $ do                                           -- ← bang
  curr <- V.new v
  forM_ [0..(v-1)] $ \i ->
    V.write curr i $ V.create $ do
      ivec <- V.new v
      forM_ [0..(v-1)] $ \j -> do
        let d = distance g prev i j k
        V.write ivec j d
      return ivec
  return curr

distance :: Graph -> TwoDVector -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Double
distance g _ i j 0 -- base case; 0 if same vertex, edge weight if neighbours
  | i == j    = 0.0
  | otherwise = M.findWithDefault infinity j (g ! i)
distance _ a i j k = let c1 = a ! i ! j
                        c2 = (a ! i ! (k-1))+(a ! (k-1) ! j)
                        in min c1 c2
```

However, when running this program with a 1000-node graph with 47978 edges, things does not look good at all. The memory usage is very high and the program takes way too long to run. The program was compiled with `ghc -O2`.

I rebuilt the program for profiling, and limited the number of iterations to 50:

```
 results = foldl' (fw g v) initial [1..50]
```

I then ran the program with `+RTS -p -hc` and `+RTS -p -hd`:

[image]

[image]

This is... interesting, but I guess it's showing that it's accumulating tonnes of thunks. Not good.

Ok, so after a few shots in the dark, I added a `deepseq` in `fw` to make sure `prev` *really* is evaluted:

```
let d = prev `deepseq` distance g prev i j k
```

Now things look better, and I can actually run the program to completion with constant memory usage. It's obvious that the bang on the `prev` argument was not enough.

For comparison with the previous graphs, here is the memory usage for 50 iterations after adding the `deepseq`:

[image]

[image]

Ok, so things are better, but I still have some questions:

1. Is this the correct solution for this space leak? I am wrong in feeling that inserting a `deepseq` is a bit ugly?
2. Is my usage of `Vector`s here idiomatic/correct? I'm building a completely new vector for every iteration and hoping that the garbage collector will delete the old `Vector`s.
3. Is there any other things I could do to make this run faster with this approach?

For references, here is `graph.txt`: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?45147f7caf8c5f29#7tiCiPovPHWRm1XNvrSb/zNl3ujF3xB3yehrxhEdVWw=

Here is `main`:

```
main = do
  ls <- fmap lines $ readFile "graph.txt"
  let numVerts = head . map read . words . head $ ls
  let edges = map (map read . words) (tail ls)
  let g = V.create $ do
        g' <- V.new numVerts
        forM_ [0..(numVerts-1)] (\idx -> V.write g' idx M.empty)
        forM_ edges $ \[f,t,w] -> do
          -- subtract one from vertex IDs so we can index directly
          curr <- V.read g' (f-1)
          V.write g' (f-1) $ M.insert (t-1) (fromIntegral w) curr
        return g'
  let a = allPairsShortestPaths g numVerts
  case a of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Negative cycle detected."
    Just a' -> do
      putStrLn  $ "The shortest, shortest path has length "
              ++ show ((V.minimum . V.map V.minimum) a')
```

Comment: a side remark: `any not $ map (\i -> a ! i ! i >= 0) [0..(V.length a-1)]` is just `any (\i -> a ! i ! i < 0) [0..(V.length a-1)]`.

Comment: did you try rewriting your `foldl'` and `forM_` calculations as explicit loops using mutable Vectors? (as done e.g. [in `test0` here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/24968/9064), though with Arrays, not Vectors. and [here with loops in place of usual `forM`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15026238/849891))

Comment: @WillNess: No, the only thing I tried was to replace `foldl'` with a tail-recursive function with a strict accumulator, but that did not seem to have an effect. It's a bit disheartening to see that both examples you link to are littered with `unsafe*` functions – I really hoped it was possible to achieve reasonable performance without resorting to that. :-)

Comment: You should be using unboxed vectors. Those will make the contents forced by simply being inserted into the vector.  The unsafe stuff in those examples is just about removing bounds-checking.

Comment: Your `TwoDVector`s are just matrices, right? Have you considered using Repa for this? Simon Marlow's implements FW as an example in several different contexts, like this: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch05.html#sec_par-repa-array-ops

Comment: @Carl: Yeah, I think you're right. I cannot create an unboxed vector of unboxed vectors, though, so I would have to store the data as one vector or change to something other than `Vector`.

Comment: @ChadScherrer: I'm currently reading Marlow's book. I'll test Repa when I come to that chapter. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, some general code cleanup:

In your `fw` function, you explicitly allocate and fill mutable vectors. However, there is a premade function for this exact purpose, namely `generate`. `fw` can therefore be rewritten as

```
V.generate v (\i -> V.generate v (\j -> distance g prev i j k))
```

Similarly, the graph generation code can be replaced with `replicate` and `accum`:

```
let parsedEdges = map (\[f,t,w] -> (f - 1, (t - 1, fromIntegral w))) edges
let g = V.accum (flip (uncurry M.insert)) (V.replicate numVerts M.empty) parsedEdges
```

Note that this totally removes all need for mutation, without losing any performance.

Now, to the actual questions:

1. In my experience, `deepseq` is very useful, but only as quick fix to space leaks like this one. The fundamental problem is not that you need to force the results after you've produced them. Instead, the use of `deepseq` implies that you should have been building the structure more strictly in the first place. In fact, if you add a bang pattern in your vector creation code like so:

   ```
   let !d = distance g prev i j k
   ```

   Then the problem is fixed without `deepseq`. Note that this doesn't work with the `generate` code, because, for some reason (I might create a feature request for this), `vector` does not provide strict functions for boxed vectors. However, when I get to unboxed vectors in answer to question 3, which are strict, both approaches work without strictness annotations.
2. As far as I know, the pattern of repeatedly generating new vectors is idiomatic. The only thing not idiomatic is the use of mutability - except when they are strictly necessary, mutable vectors are generally discouraged.
3. There are a couple of things to do:

   - Most simply, you can replace `Map Int` with `IntMap`. As that isn't really the slow point of the function, this doesn't matter too much, but `IntMap` can be much faster for heavy workloads.
   - You can switch to using unboxed vectors. Although the outer vector has to remain boxed, as vectors of vectors can't be unboxed, the inner vector can be. This also solves your strictness problem - because unboxed vectors are strict in their elements, you don't get a space leak. Note that on my machine, this improves the performance from 4.1 seconds to 1.3 seconds, so the unboxing is very helpful.
   - You can flatten the vector into a single one and use multiplication and division to switch between two dimensional indicies and one dimentional indicies. I don't recommend this, as it is a bit involved, quite ugly, and, due to the division, actually slows down the code on my machine.
   - You can use `repa`. This has the huge advantage of automatically parallelizing your code. Note that, since `repa` flattens its arrays and apparently doesn't properly get rid of the divisions needed to fill nicely (it's possible to do with nested loops, but I think it uses a single loop and a division), it has the same performance penalty as I mentioned above, bringing the runtime from 1.3 seconds to 1.8. However, if you enable parallelism and use a multicore machine, you start seeing some benifits. Unfortunately, you current test case is too tiny to see much benifit, so, on my 6 core machine, I see it drop back down to 1.2 seconds. If I up the size back to `[1..v]` instead of `[1..50]`, the parallelism brings it from 32 seconds to 13. Presumably, if you give this program a larger input, you might see more benifit.

     If you're interested, I've posted my `repa`-ified version [here](http://lpaste.net/99182).
   - EDIT: Use `-fllvm`. Testing on my computer, using `repa`, I get 14.7 seconds without parallelism, which is almost as good as without `-fllvm` and with parallelism. In general, LLVM can just handle array based code like this very well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into this over the next days – lots of great information here. :)