# Haskell Vector performance woes

Tags: performance, haskell, vector, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I wrote the classic prime number sieve algorithm in C which pretty much instantly generates all the primes smaller than 1,000,000 on my machine (I didn't do anything to optimize it).

In Haskell I use a `Vector` of `Int`s, and generate an update list for each prime number which sets the multiples to zero. This is basically the same thing as I do in C with a nested `for` loop:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

--| generate primes smaller than p
sievePrimes :: Int -> U.Vector Int
sievePrimes p = foldl f ns [0..p-1]
    where
        ns = U.fromList $ 0:[2..p]
        f v i
            | v U.! i == 0 = v
            | otherwise = v U.// [((i + 1)*k - 1, 0) | k <- [2..p `div` (i + 1)]]
```

The Haskell version runs about 1000 times slower than the C version. All I've done to optimize is to use the `vector` package. The algorithm is the same.

Why is it running so much slower? Isn't `Vector` efficient enough?

I compiled both C and Haskell with `-O2`.

Comment: [the genuine sieve of erastothenes](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf)

Comment: There are so, so many questions on SO about prime number generation in Haskell. Did you search before you asked? If so, please take some time to outline what isn't covered well by the other questions. If not... no time like the present!

Comment: no offense but the linked question really seems to be basically the same and has an outstanding answer - together with the linked article from rampion you should be good to go - if not please appologize

Comment: cf. https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array. More efficient is to use mutable array, like in https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Using_ST_Array. There's a version of it by Daniel Fischer somewhere on CodeReview, using loops instead of `forM`, and `unsafeWrite`, which runs substantially faster. Otherwise, consult the `arithmoi` package.

Comment: found it for you: [Daniel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15026238); [my Ideone entry](http://ideone.com/j24jxV) w/ odds-only array version of it, consistently 1.6x slower than a [comparable C++ version](http://ideone.com/fapob).  and [an *immutable array* version](http://ideone.com/rhj9ub) which is about 9.6x slower than the C++ version. overall, we have STUArray(unsafeWrite,loops) | STUArray(writeArray,forM) | UArray(segmented) | UArray(contiguous accumulating array) speed ratios vs. the C++ as `1.6x | 4.8x | 9.6x | 11x-13x`.

Comment: to clarify: the last one is the [odds-only version](http://ideone.com/RzqLP). [the one on the wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array) is [32x slower](http://ideone.com/dE0iU) than C++.

Comment: @WillNess, the `arithmoi` sieves are not to be trusted. They're poorly documented and extremely complicated, and until recently one of them had a tendency to segfault.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your `foldl` call with `foldl f ns [0 .. floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ p]`. This radically improves the time complexity, as explained in the [haskell-wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers), **because [the cost of `U.//` is `O(m+n)`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.11/vector-0.11.0.0/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#g:15) instead of `O(n)` as it is in languages with destructive update**, like C; which is the reason why not stopping as soon as possible doesn't worsen the time complexity there.

But in Haskell it is crucial to stop as soon as possible with immutable data, where the time complexity of the update operation is worse, as it is for lists and `Vector`s too.

When analyzing the performance of a piece of code, always analyze its [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)  by measuring its speed at several problem size points and calculating *`logBase (n2/n1) (t2/t1)`*.

The updated code, interpreted in GHCi on my computer, generates the `n = 78,498` primes below `N = 1,000,000` in 3.53s, running at *~N<sup>**1.1**</sup>* or *~n<sup>**1.2**</sup>*, which is very decent.

Your code, measured at `N = 40,000/20,000`, runs at *~N<sup>**1.7**</sup>* or *~n<sup>**1.9**</sup>*, which is terribly slow; the projected run time to 1,000,000 is 7 minutes, if the complexity stays the same.