# Python generator and set(generator) get different results

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have code like below

```
def yield_multiple():
    for prime in prime_list:
        for multiple in range(prime+prime, end, prime):
            yield multiple
```

And I use this to get the prime numbers

```
multiple_set = set(yield_multiple())
result = [v for v in candidate_list if v not in multiple_set]
```

And I meet the memory error when the set is very large, so I was thinking to use this to save the memory

```
result = [v for v in candidate_list if v not in yield_multiple()]
```

But this will get the wrong result. So, How to avoid memory error to get the prime numbers correctly?

Here's my improved solution without too much memory to use.

```
import math
import sys

import time
from mpi4py import MPI

import eratosthenes

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

TAG_RESULT = 0

n = sys.argv[1]
if n.isdigit():
    start_time = time.time()
    n = int(n)
    sqrt_n = int(math.sqrt(n))

    task_per_block = int(math.ceil((n - 1) / size))
    begin = 2 + rank * task_per_block
    end = begin + task_per_block if begin + task_per_block <= n + 1 else n + 1
    if rank == 0:
        begin = sqrt_n if sqrt_n < end else begin
    sieve_list = [True] * (end - begin)
    prime_list = eratosthenes.sieve(sqrt_n)

    if rank == 0:
        result = sum(prime_list)
        for prime in prime_list:
            start = begin if begin % prime == 0 else (int(begin / prime) + 1) * prime
            for multiple in range(start, end, prime):
                sieve_list[multiple - begin] = False
        result += sum(i + begin for i, v in enumerate(sieve_list) if v)
        result_received = 0
        while result_received < size - 1:
            data = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=TAG_RESULT)
            result += data
            result_received += 1
        print(result)
        print(time.time() - start_time)
    else:
        for prime in prime_list:
            start = begin if begin % prime == 0 else (int(begin / prime) + 1) * prime
            for multiple in range(start, end, prime):
                sieve_list[multiple - begin] = False
        result = sum(i + begin for i, v in enumerate(sieve_list) if v)
        comm.send(result, dest=0, tag=TAG_RESULT)
```

Comment: Why do you do `for multiple in range(prime, end, prime)` when you are trying to extract prime numbers? You may want to take a look at the Sieve or Eratosthenes algorithm.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, I knew Sieve of Eratosthenes. But I was trying to do a disturbed version of Sieve of Eratosthenes. So this is a pretty way to get all multiple for a given range

Comment: for a distributed sieve you may need to merge the streams of multiples in a tree, e.g. like [the one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12563800/849891).

Comment: @WillNess You are right. It should be `for multiple in range(prime+prime, end, prime)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ enumerating the multiples as arithmetic sequences of primes is exactly the essence of the Sieve of Eratosthenes though.

Comment: @WillNess I think last time I forget to add [2, 3] at the beginning.  Now,
 it is correct. thanks for your help[https://tio.run/##fZLPboMwDMbveYocSYuq/tF2qMZ1T7AbYigr7oiUBBYCU5@eOUmBUFXLCZzP9s@f095s3ejTOArVNsZSxW1NiKYZPez3e0JIBVd64boSFbdQGq6/IZFCCcvOhOIZuOwB5S/@T@iLAQXaYuToI7@1kHBXvVGfSbf0EJLduQmQVRDMsSDfZku9@Wrp8JnR1ztgJ2BYY7VGKCil6BxJfkzpqfBxr5zjH6aHgm5oMnMxr7o2hgK/1KXu1RcYbPqvB57rGtXOo@Ri0azBdrxtQVdJpGUrqaNQvbSiRQcRITSOuTYxZbq4m8ZxtgZYu5BPDQr0453LLizBgO2NjmDvRvtllVNOgvhnJJt8cMA@xdGGneBl4t7Urvsx1ukZi3ieTxhKbEMpHEVXafh@mCS8nCkfCQ10@DMvHEvkg@8xPNugZm5pA9WNddcPo2lWEGyK@BJ0EiozRsbxDw]

Comment: @WillNess I've got a better solution now. You can check it above. It will be 20x faster than the single core when I am using 48 cores

Comment: @WillNess with 10 billion to calculate

Comment: you're most welcome. --- instead of adding it to the question, I think you should post it as an answer (with some explanations) and accept it, if it answers your original question. it is perfectly OK to post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By switching to working by segments between squares of consecutive primes, creating these sets for each segment one after another.

For each segment you'll have to calculate the starting point of the enumeration  of a prime's multiples, for each known prime which is not greater than the segment's top value (i.e. the next *"core"* prime's square).

The *"core"* primes, to get the squares of, you can get separately, independently, by a recursive application of the same algorithm.

An example of this approach (the separate primes supply that is) is [How to implement an efficient infinite generator of prime numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python/10733621#10733621)

To make it *parallel*, you'll need to find means to use the set in a shared fashion between all the enumerations, which each will set each of its enumerated multiples *off* in the same shared set. Order of operations is not important, as long as they are all finished. The access need not be guarded, as setting the same location *off* twice (or more) is perfectly fine.

This will also be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with this approach - which does have a certain simplicity, although it must be terribly inefficient - the simplest way I can see to do it without constructing a large set or re-running `yield_multiple` for each candidate is to sort of reverse your membership check:

```
multiples = {c for c in yield_multiple() if c in candidate_list}
result = [c for c in candidate_list if c not in multiples]
```

However, unless using your own code is the most important factor here, I'd recommend finding a more efficient approach, like for example the one described [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068412/9200529).

Comment: Sorry to mislead you guys. I don't want to find a faster way to get the prime numbers. This is my parallel programming coursework. Basically, I was trying to parallel Sieve of Eratosthenes. I should start another question.

Comment: @BlaiseWang no need. I edited the tags on your question.